# Luxand SDK not installing in iPhone5C

Tags: ios, face-recognition

We are creating an app in which we are using the Luxand Library for face detection and recognition. We started with your “LiveRecognition” Sample App. We found that if we change the “Valid Architecture” in Project’s “Build Setting” from “armv7” to "armv7s" and “arm64” it gives us around 50 compile time error.Below is the error that I get while compiling. We just wanted to know, how do I compile the app successfully with "arm64" and “armv7s”. Could you let us what configurational changes needs to be done on the App’s Project "Build Setting” so as to run the project? Also let us know if you need any further assistance from us regarding the Project’s "Build Setting” setting.

Also,we see in your website that you support arm64/x86_64 (iPhone 5S+, iPad Air+, iPad mini retina+, simulator). So,we just wanted to know if you support iPhone5c as well, as we are getting the issue in iPhone5c.

The Project Setting for my project is:
Architechures : Standard Architechtures(armv7, arm64)
Base SDK : Latest iOS (iOS 8.3)
Build Active Architecture Only: NO
Valid Architechture: arm64, armv7,armv7s

iOS Deployment Target: iOS7.0

Other Linker Flag: -lxml2

ERROR:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file <Path To project>/libfsdk-static_64.a, missing required architecture armv7 in file<Path To project>/libfsdk-static_64.a (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_FSDK_LockID", referenced from:
      -[DetectionViewController processImageAsyncWith:] in DetectionViewController.o
  "_FSDK_SetName", referenced from:
      -[DetectionViewController processImageAsyncWith:] in DetectionViewController.o
  "_FSDK_SaveTrackerMemoryToFile", referenced from:
      -[DetectionViewController unloadView] in DetectionViewController.o
  "_FSDK_FeedFrame", referenced from:
      -[RecognitionViewController processImageAsyncWith:] in RecognitionViewController.o
      -[CaptureImages processImageAsyncWith:] in CaptureImages.o
      -[DetectionViewController processImageAsyncWith:] in DetectionViewController.o
  "_FSDK_GetTrackerEyes", referenced from:
      -[RecognitionViewController processImageAsyncWith:] in RecognitionViewController.o
      -[CaptureImages processImageAsyncWith:] in CaptureImages.o
      -[DetectionViewController processImageAsyncWith:] in DetectionViewController.o
  "_FSDK_MirrorImage", referenced from:
      -[RecognitionViewController processImageAsyncWith:] in RecognitionViewController.o
      -[CaptureImages processImageAsyncWith:] in CaptureImages.o
      -[DetectionViewController processImageAsyncWith:] in DetectionViewController.o
  "_FSDK_LoadTrackerMemoryFromFile", referenced from:
      -[RecognitionViewController setupCamera] in RecognitionViewController.o
      -[CaptureImages initWithCamera:] in CaptureImages.o
      -[DetectionViewController setupCamera] in DetectionViewController.o
  "_FSDK_ClearTracker", referenced from:
      -[RecognitionViewController processImageAsyncWith:] in RecognitionViewController.o
      -[CaptureImages processImageAsyncWith:] in CaptureImages.o
      -[DetectionViewController processImageAsyncWith:] in DetectionViewController.o
  "_FSDK_CreateTracker", referenced from:
      -[RecognitionViewController setupCamera] in RecognitionViewController.o
      -[CaptureImages initWithCamera:] in CaptureImages.o
      -[DetectionViewController setupCamera] in DetectionViewController.o
  "_FSDK_LoadImageFromBuffer", referenced from:
      -[RecognitionViewController processImageAsyncWith:] in RecognitionViewController.o
      -[CaptureImages processImageAsyncWith:] in CaptureImages.o
      -[DetectionViewController processImageAsyncWith:] in DetectionViewController.o
  "_FSDK_SetNumThreads", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_FSDK_SetTrackerMultipleParameters", referenced from:
      -[RecognitionViewController setupCamera] in RecognitionViewController.o
      -[CaptureImages initWithCamera:] in CaptureImages.o
      -[DetectionViewController setupCamera] in DetectionViewController.o
  "_FSDK_GetAllNames", referenced from:
      -[RecognitionViewController processImageAsyncWith:] in RecognitionViewController.o
      -[CaptureImages processImageAsyncWith:] in CaptureImages.o
      -[DetectionViewController processImageAsyncWith:] in DetectionViewController.o
  "_FSDK_GetLicenseInfo", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_FSDK_CreateEmptyImage", referenced from:
      -[RecognitionViewController processImageAsyncWith:] in RecognitionViewController.o
      -[CaptureImages processImageAsyncWith:] in CaptureImages.o
      -[DetectionViewController processImageAsyncWith:] in DetectionViewController.o
  "_FSDK_Initialize", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_FSDK_UnlockID", referenced from:
      -[DetectionViewController processImageAsyncWith:] in DetectionViewController.o
  "_FSDK_GetNumThreads", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_FSDK_FreeImage", referenced from:
      -[RecognitionViewController processImageAsyncWith:] in RecognitionViewController.o
      -[CaptureImages processImageAsyncWith:] in CaptureImages.o
      -[DetectionViewController processImageAsyncWith:] in DetectionViewController.o
  "_FSDK_ActivateLibrary", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_FSDK_RotateImage90", referenced from:
      -[RecognitionViewController processImageAsyncWith:] in RecognitionViewController.o
      -[CaptureImages processImageAsyncWith:] in CaptureImages.o
      -[DetectionViewController processImageAsyncWith:] in DetectionViewController.o
  "_FSDK_SetFaceDetectionThreshold", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: It looks like you only have the 64 bit version of at least one of your libraries.
Your compiler is now looking for the version intended for the armv7/armv7s version of the library, and can't find it.
The simple solution : find out which library it is, and include the non-64 bit version.

Comment: How do I get the non-64 bit version of Luxand Library. They just have two static files: `libfsdk-static_64.a` and `libfsdk-static.a` which is already included in the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the following in the Build Setting:

```
Architectures : Standard Architechtures(armv7, arm64) 
Base SDK : Latest iOS (iOS 8.3) 
Build Active Architecture Only: NO
Valid Architechture: armv7, arm64
iOS Deployment Target: iOS7.0
C++ Language Dialect: GNU++11[-std=gnu++11]
C++ Standard Library: libstdc++ (GNU C++ standard library)
```